# SQL Use ID to count dates but only can count each once

Tags: sql, sql-server

**TABLE 1**

```
  ID   DATE
  1 . 1/1/2018
  2 . 1/2/2018
  2 . 1/2/2018
  3 . 1/3/2018
  4 . 1/2/2018
```

So I need to get a count of each date but there are cases where the same ID has the same date. I need to only count that one once.

For example my expected output is

```
  1/1/2018 .  1
  1/2/2018 .  2
  1/3/2018 .  1
```

But the output i'm getting is

```
  1/1/2018 .  1
  1/2/2018 .  3
  1/3/2018 .  1
```

Comment: You should post your query in question as well in order to rectify issue.

Comment: So the row `4 . 1/2/2018` does not count in your expected output?

Comment: It does count in my output but I don't want it to count one of the dates with the id of 2.

Comment: So there is an extra row `1/2/2018 .  1`  in your expected output?

Comment: yes an extra one is being counted. Yogesh solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` to considered same id as once :

```
SELECT DATE, COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM table1 t
GROUP BY DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP` by ID and DATE:

```
SELECT ID, DATE, COUNT(DATE) AS COUNTER
FROM table1
GROUP BY ID, DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery where you concatenate the key and the date using distinct.

```
SELECT DATE, COUNT(DATE) FROM table1 
where DATE + ID = 
(select DATE + ID from table1) 
group by DATE
```